# YouTrack: suppress notifications for some field

Tags: youtrack

I subscribed to changes notification for issues on our YT server (7.0 version), but I don't want to get notifications when someone changes only [Spent Time] field (through time tracking tab).

Is it possible to make such exception somehow (maybe through workflow rules)?

Answer (score 0):

Current YouTrack version (7.0) doesn't provide such a functionality. The only way I can suggest you is to disable change notifications and write a rule that will send you notifications about the fields you are interested in.

As another workaround you can simply set up a filter in your mailbox and send messages with "Spent time" in body text right into junk.

Comment: Filtering out the mails containing "Spent time" is too aggressive: there can be other changes listed in the mail that should not be lost.